# Debugging mode not working even in new project of android studio giraffe

Tags: android-studio

[Debugging not starting even after the new project started. I tried the gradle update but it doesn't seems to be working. As project started it gets the debugging mode shocked results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geqEE.png)

Debugging mode show shock as the project started.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.